# Write a java program to get a Date as String in the format “dd-MM-yyyy”

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws ParseException{
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the date");
        String p=sc.nextLine();

        SimpleDateFormat d=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);        
        SimpleDateFormat i=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        try {
           Date m=d.parse(p);
           System.out.println("The input date is"+i.format(m));
        } catch(ParseException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

when I am running this problem I am getting error as

> java.text.ParseException:Unparseable date: "27-01-1978" at
>   java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366) at
>   Main.main(Main.java:19).

What should be done in order to avoid that error.

Comment: Both of your `SimpleDateFormat` objects are created with the same pattern (dd/MM/yyyy) - was that intentional?

Comment: You need to provide a format that's matches the date you want to parse. 
 If your date is supposed to have dashes, don't put slashes in your formatter.  Voting to close as your issue is down to a typo and thus unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: Already answered in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/4101906), and yes @JoeC is right!

Comment: Maybe try input a date formatted as you set in your code, like: `27/01/1978`

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

It’s very basic:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatterWithHyphens = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
    DateTimeFormatter formatterWithSlashes = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(p, formatterWithHyphens);
    System.out.println("The input date is" + date.format(formatterWithSlashes));
```

Output

> The input date is27/01/1978

I recommend you avoid the classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. They are long outdated, and the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead I am using and recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. Generally it is so much nicer to work with.

### What went wrong in your code

You just needed to use the pattern that you gave yourself in your question title: dd-MM-yyyy. When you input date has hyphens (dashes) in it, then the format pattern string needs to have them too.

Then why did I use `uuuu` instead of `yyyy`? I really could have used `yyyy` with `java.time` too, for years in the common era (“anno domini”) there is no difference. `uuuu` is a signed year, so 0 equals 1 BCE, 1 equals 2 BCE, etc. My habit is to use `uuuu` unless there is a reason for `yyyy`.

In addition: use more explanatory variable names than `d`, `i`, `m` and `p`. I believe this will make it easier for yourself.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [`DateTimeFormatter` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with the pattern letters for this class